# CSS and HTML to place offset content over image to produce staggered effect

Tags: html, css

I currently have a 'working' layout for my site which features a style I really like where I have a content offset and overlaying an image. It's almost where I want it - currently the images are all centred perfectly and each alternate text box overlaps either the right or left side like so:

[image]

However, I'd like to make it so that each alternating row has the image pulled either to the left or right and the text box still overlapping on the opposite side like this:

[image]

I'm sort of at a loss here, what is the best way to achieve this?

Pen:  https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XLeGNN

```css
.image-block-container {
  font-family: Arial;
}

.image-block-container img {
  display: block;
  margin:0 auto;
  width: 100%;
}

.text-block-right {
  position:relative;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.09) 0px 0px 12px 4px;
  line-height: 28px;
  font-weight: 100;
  text-align: left;
  background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  color: black;
  padding:20px;
  bottom: 35%;
  max-width: 300px;
  margin-top: -120px !important;
  word-wrap:break-word;
  margin:0 auto;
  line-height:35px;
}

.text-block-left {
  position:relative;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.09) 0px 0px 12px 4px;
  line-height: 28px;
  font-weight: 100;
  text-align: left;
  background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  color: black;
  padding:20px;
  bottom: 35%;
  max-width: 300px;
  margin-top: -120px !important;
  word-wrap:break-word;
  margin:0 auto;
  line-height:35px;
}


@media (min-width: 768px){
    
  .image-block-container {
    position: relative;
  }
  
  .image-block-container img {
    width: 65%;
    margin:0 auto;
  }
  
  .text-block-right {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 20%;
    right: 5%;
    max-width:550px;
  }

  .text-block-left {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 20%;
    left: 5%;
    max-width:550px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="image-block-container">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/1280x900" alt="about_us" />
    <div class="text-block-right">
        <h1>About Us</h1>
        We are building a first of a kind network of doctors who offer Direct Primary Care and Anti-Aging (Cosmetic
        Dermatology) medical memberships for patients who want optimum healthcare driven by the latest in technology and
        -- we offer a concierge service (management and patient referral service) for doctors that specializes in
        converting "insurance" practices to the "membership" model.
    </div>
</div>

<div class="image-block-container">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/1280x900" alt="about_us" />
    <div class="text-block-left">
        <h1>About Us</h1>
        We are building a first of a kind network of doctors who offer Direct Primary Care and Anti-Aging (Cosmetic
        Dermatology) medical memberships for patients who want optimum healthcare driven by the latest in technology and
        -- we offer a concierge service (management and patient referral service) for doctors that specializes in
        converting "insurance" practices to the "membership" model.
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach would be to use [flex box](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox) on the `.image-block-container` element. This enables simpler and more robust row alignment of elements, with vertical centring (ie via `align-items:center`).

By using flex-box in this way, you can then achieve the overlap of the `text-block` by translating it via a CSS transform. In the snippet below, I translate the `text-block` by `50%` along the x axis to centre the text block on the edge of the image.

Finally, the `left-overlap` "modifier" CSS class is introduced to modify the ordering an layout of elements at the `.image-block-container` level - this enables the placement of the `text-block` and ordering of flex box elements to be adjusted for the `left-overlap` case:

```css
.image-block-container {
  font-family: Arial;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  /* Use flex box with row orrientation */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  /* Vertically center children */
  align-items: center;
}

.text-block {
  /* Cause text block to tranlate by half width to
  overlap the image */
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  max-width: 25rem;
  background: pink;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.left-overlap img {
  /* If left overlap case, then change the ordering
  of the img to set it after the adjacent text block */
  order: 1;
}

.left-overlap .text-block {
  /* Translate text block in opposite direction for
  left overlap case */
  transform: translateX(50%);
}


/* Mobile */

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .image-block-container {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .text-block {
    width:75%;
  }
  .left-overlap img {
    order: 0;
  }
  .left-overlap .text-block, .text-block {
    transform: translateY(-50%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="image-block-container right-overlap">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/1280x500" alt="about_us" />
  <div class="text-block">
    <h1>About Us</h1>
    We are building a first of a kind network of doctors who offer Direct Primary Care and Anti-Aging (Cosmetic Dermatology) medical memberships for patients who want optimum healthcare driven by the latest in technology and -- we offer a concierge service
    (management and patient referral service) for doctors that specializes in converting "insurance" practices to the "membership" model.
  </div>
</div>


<div class="image-block-container left-overlap">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/1280x500" alt="about_us" />
  <div class="text-block">
    <h1>About Us</h1>
    We are building a first of a kind network of doctors who offer Direct Primary Care and Anti-Aging (Cosmetic Dermatology) medical memberships for patients who want optimum healthcare driven by the latest in technology and -- we offer a concierge service
    (management and patient referral service) for doctors that specializes in converting "insurance" practices to the "membership" model.
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this is of some help!

Comment: Thank you! I accepted your answer since it seems to do exactly what I need. Can this also be used so that on mobile resize it pushes the text to overlap the bottom center of the image instead?

Comment: @TomN. thank you for that - yes it certainly can be. I'll update the answer for that

Comment: @TomN. just extended the CSS with responsive mobile styling - hope that helps :)

Comment: Noo problems :)

Comment: Can you possibly tell me what I'm doing wrong here http://mymdhome.com/ ? It seems right-overlap is perfect, but left-overlap is doing the opposite of what I want (mobile size is fine though)

Comment: Seems your `img` elements are inside `p` elements which will cause issues

Comment: Ah, I see now. Thanks for that, I guess that's a wordpress issue I'll have to work around